# Meteor roles not being added... what am I missing?

Tags: meteor

I have the following which should create a user (and does), and then add roles to that user. The user get created, but the role does not (no errors)... any idea why?

```js
Meteor.startup(function () {
  var users = [
    {
      fname:"Normal", lname: "User" , email:"normal@epdemo.com",
          roles:['normal'], group: 'demo2016'
    },
  ];

  _.each(users, function (user) {
    if (!Meteor.users.findOne({emails: {$elemMatch: {address: user.email}}})) {
      var id;
      id = Accounts.createUser({
        email: user.email,
        password: "epdemo1",
        profile: { firstName: user.fname, lastName: user.lname }
      });
      if (user.roles.length > 0) {
        // Need _id of existing user record so this call must come
        // after `Accounts.createUser` or `Accounts.onCreate`
        Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, user.roles, user.group);
        console.log("ID :", id));
        console.log("Roles :", Roles.getRolesForUser(id));
      }
    };
  });
});
```

TIA!

Comment: what is `Roles` and `Roles.addUsersToRoles`? Where and how is that defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that when calling `getRolesForUser`, you must pass in your group name otherwise you'll get an empty set back:

```
Roles.getRolesForUser(id, 'demo2016')
```

There is an open issue for this:
https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/issues/68

Comment: Thanks Mark...I added the group, but the result is still an empty array. Just started using the Roles package, are there any allow/deny aspects that I may be missing or anything else anyone can think of?

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out... it was because the Roles array and Group were not defined in the Users schema. I added them and now it's all good. I am going to accept Mark's answer too though because without it, even after I did this I would have run into https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/issues/68 and spent even more time on this.

I guess SimpleSchema just ignores fields not present in the Schema.